# Sails.js returns 404 when a 2MB file is returned as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, express, sails.js

When I try to return to the caller the contents of a 2MB file, `sails` terminates the response and returns `404`. Here is the relevant code:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      height = parseInt(req.param('height'), 10),
      filePath = `ebook.css`;
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, css){
if(err){
    return res.serverError({error: 'Can not open CSS file.'});
}
return res.json({ebook: {
    title: publication.title,
    numPages: publication.numPages,
    thumbs: thumbs,
    css: css
}});
```

The call is `AJAX` and if I take out the `css` key, all works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Freakin sails man, I'm still waiting for deep populate.

Comment: "I guess this breaks the JSON encoding". Is there an error? What is it? If not, stick a bunch of `log` calls in the code to make sure everything is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file contains some curly braces and, I guess, this breaks the `JSON` encoding. But why? The file content is string so shouldn't it be put in the `JSON` value without further parsing?

Comment: Please do not post questions as an answer.